# Can I group/sum/combine two values in a Google Pie Chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-pie-chart

[In this attached image,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydks6.jpg)

Instead of having separate 12.4% and 8.3%, is it possible to show their values summed up and combined? 20.7% - over both red slices ?

The main important thing is to know the total carbs percent, while still be aware of how much of it is sugar.

Thank you !

Comment: If possible, I want to see both light red and dark red slices - and have their sum on top. This way I know the total carbs and be aware of the sugar content from it.